# Analysis on Improper Integrals

Tags: analysis, improper-integrals

This question is from Munkres' Analysis on Manifolds, section 15 question 1.

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be the function $f(x) = x$. Show that, given $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists a sequence $C_N$ of compact rectifiable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ whose union is $\mathbb{R}$, such that $C_N \subset \operatorname{Int} \, C_{N+1}$ for each $N$ and 
$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \int_{C_N} f = \lambda. $$ 
Does the extended integral $\int_\mathbb{R} f$ exist?

My guess is to have $C_0$ be $\lambda$ and not the point $-\lambda$.  Then $C_i$ be $[\lambda - i, \lambda +i]$ and $[-\lambda - i, -\lambda +i] \setminus -\lambda$.  This would cover $\mathbb{R}$ and the integral would hold.  I'm not sure if this makes sense though.  Also the extended integral wouldn't exist (would be infinity) but a theorem in the section says that if the normal integral exists, then the extended integral exists as well.

Comment: I think the point of the exercise is that the extended integral *doesn't* exist. Given $\lambda$, you can find a sequence of sets cover $\mathbb{R}$ such that you can integrate $f$ and get $\lambda$. But this works for every possible $\lambda$, so there's no way to properly define the integral of $f$ over $\mathbb{R}$ independent of the limiting sequence you're using.

Answer (score 1):

There are many possibilities, but one way to construct the $C_n$ would be as follows. I will use the notation that $B(x_0,r) = [x_0 - r, x_0 + r]$. First, notice that
$$ \int_{B(x_0,r)} f(x) \, dx = \int_{x_0 - r}^{x_0 + r} x \, dx = 2x_0 r $$
Now, fix $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. Pick $|x_0|$ very small such that $r = \lambda/(2x_0)$ is much larger than $1$. Now set $C_0 = B(x_0, r)$. Then $\int_{C_0} f \, dx = \lambda$. Now define $C_n$ for $n \geq 1$ by $C_n = B(2^{-n}x_0, 2^n r)$. Then $C_{n-1} \subset C_n$ and $\int_{C_n} f \, dx = \lambda$ for each $n$. Furthermore, since $C_n$ is expanding exponentially, then there union covers $\mathbb{R}$.